# Decorate a python function to work as a Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services, google-cloud-platform

I wrote this for a class project, the backend for this [dog voting website](https://socialchoice.nuphilosophy.com/). I noticed duplicate code among multiple functions I was writing to be deployed as a cloud function: they all were wrapped in try/except blocks that returned either 200 and JSON or 500 and a traceback. (I understand that it would be better to return an informative, structured error code, but this helped with debugging and we didn't have extensive error handling on the front-end: this was a loss I was willing to take).

The decorator gives each function a connection pool, uses jsonschema to validate input and output, responds to CORS OPTIONS from anywhere, and uses print statements for logging. This isn't great, but it was far easier to set up than the Google Cloud Function logging library, and everything printed to stdout during function execution is logged to GCP Stackdriver.

Here is the decorator itself:

```
import functools
import json
import traceback

import jsonschema
from util.get_pool import get_pool

pg_pool = None


def cloudfunction(in_schema=None, out_schema=None):
    """

    :param in_schema: the schema for the input, or a falsy value if there is no input
    :param out_schema: the schema for the output, or a falsy value if there is no output
    :return: the cloudfunction wrapped function
    """
    # Both schemas must be valid according to jsonschema draft 7, if they are provided.
    if in_schema:
        jsonschema.Draft7Validator.check_schema(in_schema)
    if out_schema:
        jsonschema.Draft7Validator.check_schema(out_schema)

    def cloudfunction_decorator(f):
        """ Wraps a function with two arguments, the first of which is a json object that it expects to be sent with the
        request, and the second is a postgresql pool. It modifies it by:
         - setting CORS headers and responding to OPTIONS requests with `Allow-Origin *`
         - passing a connection from a global postgres connection pool
         - adding logging, of all inputs as well as error tracebacks.

        :param f: A function that takes a `request` and a `pgpool` and returns a json-serializable object
        :return: a function that accepts one argument, a Flask request, and calls f with the modifications listed
        """

        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapped(request):
            global pg_pool

            if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                return cors_options()

            # If it's not a CORS OPTIONS request, still include the base header.
            headers = {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}

            if not pg_pool:
                pg_pool = get_pool()

            try:
                conn = pg_pool.getconn()

                if in_schema:
                    request_json = request.get_json()
                    print(repr({"request_json": request_json}))
                    jsonschema.validate(request_json, in_schema)
                    function_output = f(request_json, conn)
                else:
                    function_output = f(conn)

                if out_schema:
                    jsonschema.validate(function_output, out_schema)

                conn.commit()
                print(repr({"response_json": function_output}))

                response_json = json.dumps(function_output)
                # TODO allow functions to specify return codes in non-exceptional cases
                return (response_json, 200, headers)
            except:
                print("Error: Exception traceback: " + repr(traceback.format_exc()))
                return (traceback.format_exc(), 500, headers)
            finally:
                # Make sure to put the connection back in the pool, even if there has been an exception
                try:
                    pg_pool.putconn(conn)
                except NameError:  # conn might not be defined, depending on where the error happens above
                    pass

        return wrapped

    return cloudfunction_decorator


# If given an OPTIONS request, tell the requester that we allow all CORS requests (pre-flight stage)
def cors_options():
    # Allows GET and POST requests from any origin with the Content-Type
    # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
    }

    return ('', 204, headers)
```

get_pool is here:

```
from os import getenv
from psycopg2 import OperationalError, connect
from psycopg2.pool import SimpleConnectionPool

INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME = getenv('INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME', "")

POSTGRES_USER = getenv('POSTGRES_USER', "")
POSTGRES_PASSWORD = getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD', "")
POSTGRES_NAME = getenv('POSTGRES_DATABASE', "postgres")

pg_config = {
    'user': POSTGRES_USER,
    'password': POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    'dbname': POSTGRES_NAME
}


def get_pool():
    try:
        return __connect(f'/cloudsql/{INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}')
    except OperationalError:
        # If production settings fail, use local development ones
        return __connect('localhost')


def __connect(host):
    """
    Helper functions to connect to Postgres
    """
    pg_config['host'] = host
    return SimpleConnectionPool(1, 1, **pg_config)


def get_connection(host="localhost"):
    pg_config["host"] = host
    return connect(**pg_config)
```

And an example of usage:

```
@cloudfunction(
    in_schema={"type": "string"},
    out_schema={
        "anyOf": [{
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "dog1": {"type": "integer"},
                "dog2": {"type": "integer"}
            },
            "additionalProperties": False,
            "minProperties": 2,
        }, {
            "type": "null"
        }]
    })
def get_dog_pair(request_json, conn):
    [function body elided]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Decorator Function -> Decorator class

IMO, this decorator function should be a class. The use of `global pool` hints at this, the decorator needs to maintain some sort of state. It's not too bad to build, it requires `__init__` and `__call__` methods:

```py
class CloudFunction:
    def __init__(self, pool=None, in_schema=None, out_schema=None):
        for schema in (in_schema, out_schema):
            if not schema:
                continue
            jsonschema.Draft7Validator.check_schema(schema)

        self.in_schema = in_schema
        self.out_schema = out_schema
        
        self.pool = pool if pool is not None else get_pool()


    def __call__(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                return cors_options()
            
            headers = {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
            ...
```

## `get_conn` as a `contextmanager`

This is pretty much implemented as one already, since you've wrapped the creation and management of the connection in a `try`/`finally`

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager 


class CloudFunction:
    ~snip~
    @contextmanager
    def get_connection(self):
        conn = self.pool.getconn()

        try:
            yield conn
        finally:
            self.pool.putconn(conn)


    def use_conn(self):
        with self.get_connection() as conn:
            # use conn
```

However, there's a difference in the implementation. I wouldn't wrap the `self.pool.getconn` here, because I'd want that error to be raised if no connection is returned from the pool. This way you don't have to deal with the `NameError`, which feels like a hack.

## A helper function

I'd rather not have deep nesting of a `try`/`except` and `with` all defined within `__call__`. It's too many levels of indentation to keep track of and the code turns into a bit of a wall-of-text, so a quick `handle_request` helper function does nicely:

```py
class CloudFunction:
    def handle_request(self, request, func, *args, **kwargs):
        with self.get_connection() as conn:
            if self.in_schema is not None:
                request_json = request.get_json()
                print(repr({"request_json": request_json}))
                jsonschema.validate(request_json, self.in_schema)
                function_output = func(request_json, conn, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                function_output = func(conn, *args, **kwargs)

            if self.out_schema:
                jsonschema.validate(function_output, self.out_schema)

            conn.commit()
        
        response_json = json.dumps(function_output)
        return response_json

    # Wrap all of this in a try/except in here
    def __call__(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                return cors_options()
            
            headers = {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}

            try:
                resp = self.handle_request(request, func, *args, **kwargs)
                print(f"Success: {resp!r}")
                output = (resp, 200, headers)
            except Exception:
                tb = traceback.format_exc()
                print(f"Error: {tb!r}")
                output = (tb, 500, headers)

            return output 
        return wrapper
```

## Putting Everything Together

```py
class CloudFunction:
    def __init__(self, pool=None, in_schema=None, out_schema=None):
        for schema in (in_schema, out_schema):
            if not schema:
                continue

            jsonschema.Draft7Validator.check_schema(schema)

        self.in_schema = in_schema
        self.out_schema = out_schema
        
        self.pool = pool if pool is not None else get_pool()


    def __call__(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                return cors_options()
            
            headers = {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}

            try:
                resp = self.handle_request(request, func, *args, **kwargs)
                print(f"Success: {resp!r}")
                output = (resp, 200, headers)
            except Exception:
                tb = traceback.format_exc()
                print(f"Error: {tb!r}")
                output = (tb, 500, headers)

            return output 
        return wrapper

    
    def handle_request(self, request, func, *args, **kwargs):
        with self.get_connection() as conn:
            if self.in_schema is not None:
                request_json = request.get_json()
                print(repr({"request_json": request_json}))
                jsonschema.validate(request_json, self.in_schema)
                function_output = func(request_json, conn, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                function_output = func(conn, *args, **kwargs)

            if self.out_schema:
                jsonschema.validate(function_output, self.out_schema)

            conn.commit()
        
        response_json = json.dumps(function_output)
        return response_json
    

    @contextmanager
    def get_connection(self):
        conn = self.pool.getconn()

        try:
            yield conn
        finally:
            self.pool.putconn(conn)
```

## Example Usage

It should now look pretty similar:

```py
# Nice argument formatting here, by the way
@CloudFunction(
    in_schema={"type": "string"},
    out_schema={
        "anyOf": [{
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "dog1": {"type": "integer"},
                "dog2": {"type": "integer"}
            },
            "additionalProperties": False,
            "minProperties": 2,
        }, {
            "type": "null"
        }]
    })
def get_dog_pair(request_json, conn):
    [function body elided]
```